# Apache x32 or x64? (requires PHP w/MySQL & APC extensions, others)

Tags: apache-2.2, php, 64-bit

I need to reinstall Apache on my personal desktop.  The machine now runs Windows 7 x64, so I'm thinking of installing the x64 version of Apache.  However, it looks like this would lead to me needing to recompile several Apache modules (at a minimum) myself, which would probably be an annoyance.  I'm also worried about what bugs might magically appear in the 64-bit version of things like APC.

I use my machine as (1) a personal SVN server, (2) a toy webserver [for when I'm debugging personal projects in PHP], (3) a toy webserver again, with mod_rewrite, mod_ssl, mod_proxy, mod_proxy_http [for when I occasionally use the machine to work on my day job], and (4) a standard development box [so I'd like Apache to not eat up too many extra cycles if it can be avoided].

Does anyone have a good feel for the performance pros and bugginess cons of going x64?  Somewhat subjective, I know, but I'm hopeful that there will be a consensus among those with more experience than I.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a dev machine there's really no reason to deal with any hassle by attempting a move to 64 bit in your situation, IMO.